# Android ViewPager - does not display the activity's name/label

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm using `ViewPager` to display tabs with fragments. The problem is that I can't seem to be able to hide the activity's name/label from above the tabs. I'll also like to know if someone knows how to use tabs and fragments without using the `support library` since my minimum SDK is 14.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your style :

```
<style name="NoTitleTheme" parent="ParentTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

or make the following call before `setContentView` in `onCreate` :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both methods but:
When I add that item to the xml the title is still present.

When I call to requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) or supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) the aplication crashes.

Comment: crash with which error ? You need to call that in onCreate of your Activity, *before* the call to setContentView.

Comment: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_main);

    }`

And the error I get is `requestFeature() must be called before adding content`

Comment: Try moving the call to requestFeature before super.onCreate, I remember seeing some issues with this when using ActionBarSherlock so you might have the same problem : https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/310#issuecomment-7350074 Could you let me know if that works for you ? I'll edit my answer if it does to make it clearer for everyone ;)

Comment: I've moved the call to requestFeature before the call to super. The crash is gone but the title is still there :\

Comment: I have no idea why, I'm afraid. I'm guessing you don't want a quick and dirty solution, but if you're in a hurry you *could* do this : getActionBar().setCustomView(localView); where localView is an empty View you inflate yourself. Please note I'm not proud of myself writing this :)